# Why is the Chinese word "girl" or "女" not showing up on pinyin

Tags: simplified-characters

The correct pinyin of girl in Nu, but when you type nu in none of the first searches are "Nu", or even if u type just "n" for that matter.

Why does it not appear, as it is a pretty common word.

Comment: `The correct pinyin of girl in Nu` No, the correct pinyin is **nü**, and since **ü** is hard to type on a standard English keyboard layout, they substituted it with **v**.

Comment: It should show up if you just type **n**.

Answer (score 3):

Try 'nv'. It's actually 'nǚ' and since 'v' is not in mandarin pronunciation, it's quite reasonable to use 'v' in place.